# How to get the touchableOpacity function to work correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I press on "Immunity boosting" the correct Pressedinfo shows up, so its original function works, but the problem is it also alerts citrus, and when I click the touchableOpacity thats supposed to alert Citrus but I don't get any alerts when I'm supposed to, Please check code down below.........................................

```js
export default function LinksScreen() {
  const citrusAlert = () => Alert.alert("Citrus ");
  const [Pressedinfo, setPressedInfo] = useState(null)
  const pressHandler = (id) => {
    if (id == 1) {
      setPressedInfo(
        <View>
          <View style={Styles.component}>
            <Image source={home} style={Styles.home} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text2}>#Stay home, Save lives</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.component}>
            <Image source={distanceimg} style={Styles.distance} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Keep a safe distance</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.component}>
            <Image source={washinghands} style={Styles.distance} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Wash hands often</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.component}>
            <Image source={coverimg} style={Styles.distance} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Cover your cough</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={Styles.component}>
            <Image source={sickimg} style={Styles.distance} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Sick? Call for help</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      )
    } else if (id == 2) {
      setPressedInfo(<View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={citrusAlert()} style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={citrus} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Citrus (Vitamin C)</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={bellp} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Red Bell Peppers</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={broc} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Broccoli</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={garlic} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Garlic</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={ginger} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Ginger</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Image source={spinach} style={Styles.distance} />
          <Text style={Styles.Text2}>Spinach</Text>
        </View>
  
   
      </View>)
    } else if (id == 3) {
      setPressedInfo(<View>
        <View style={Styles.component}>
          <Text style={Styles.Text3}>Stay Home and Call a Health Care Provider</Text>
        </View>
      </View>)
    }
  }
  return (
    <ScrollView style={Styles.scrv} >
      <View style={Styles.container} >
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(1)}>
          <View style={Styles.container2}>
            <Image source={img5} style={Styles.Hand} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text1}> 5 rules of prevention</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(2)}>
          <View style={Styles.container2}>
            <Image source={food} style={Styles.Hand} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text1}>Immunity boosting</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => pressHandler(3)}>
          <View style={Styles.container2}>
            <Image source={sickimg} style={Styles.Hand} />
            <Text style={Styles.Text1}>Feeling Sick?</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

      </View>
      {Pressedinfo}
    </ScrollView>
  )
}
```

Comment: Try to avoid adding components into your useState hook. Instead, update your state with numbers, boolean or strings and use these values to conditionally render the components, ideally inside their own files. This way is easier to tack and debug components and changes that occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change onPress={citrusAlert()} to onPress={citrusAlert}